# Passing data down the hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, dependency-injection

I read a lot of topics about principles for writing testable code. I'm working on using Dependency Injection in my application and I'm facing a very big problem.
In the top ViewController, I'm loading an array of objects and the user can select on of them to go deeper in the hierarchy. The thing is that I need the selected object in some controllers (including the leaf controller) and for some I don't need.

In picture, it can be like this :

```
NeedObject    ->    don't need    ->    don't need    ->     need
TopController -> otherController1 -> otherController2 -> leafController
```

For now, I'm passing the selected object through all the hierarchy, but I can feel how it's bad as it does not respect the principle stating that an object should only know about what it needs. But I can't figure out how to respect this principle.

Note that the objects are all children of `ManagedObject` and are stocked in CoreData.
I thought about adding like a boolean `isSelected` in the class definition and then use an object that would request `CoreData` for the object with `selected = YES`, but I'm not sure about it as the "**selectability**" of the object should not be something persistent, right ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing info down the hierarchy is the way to do dependency injection, even if some intermediate layers have no use for that information other than passing it on further.

This is preferred over having an object deep in the hierarchy "reaching back up" to a top-level object to request the information. Lower-level objects should know little about the higher-level objects, which gives you the most flexibility to evolve your hierarchy over time.

Apple recommends defining a protocol for passing dependency injection data this way, which further isolates dependencies between classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's really helping to understand the DI concept

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are doing already is fine.

As you have described it, otherController1 and otherController2 'need' a reference to the user selected object in order to pass that reference to a lower level controller.